# Do higher level ores have better chances of giving you higher tier gems?

Tags: new-world

Sometimes when you mine an ore, you also get some gems.  But does the type of ore dictate the tier of gem you have a chance of getting?

The level required to mine each ore is:

- Iron: 0
- Silver: 10
- Gold: 45
- Starmetal: 100
- Platinum: 110
- Orichalcum: 175

Do the higher level ores have better chances of giving you higher tier gems or is it random?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. The type of ore dictates the tier of gem you can get.

From the wiki:
https://newworld.fandom.com/wiki/Raw_Gemstones

> Raw Gemstones are obtained through most of the non-elemental mining
> nodes. These nodes being Iron, Silver, Gold, Platinum, Starmetal, &
> Orichalcum. **Each node can only grant certain Tiers of raw gemstone(s)**
> pertaining to the type of node and % Miner's Luck a player has.

The various ore wiki page's also confirm this:

https://newworld.fandom.com/wiki/Iron_Vein

> Iron Veins produce Iron Ore and have no level requirement in order to
> gather. They have the potential to produce ****Tier I** Raw Gemstones** as
> well as Sparkmetal and Fae Iron, based off of the player's %Miner's
> Luck.

https://newworld.fandom.com/wiki/Silver_Vein

> Silver Veins produce Silver Ore and require level 10 in the Mining
> skill to gather, and can be tracked at level 35. They have the
> potential to also produce **Tier I & II Raw Gemstones** as well as
> Sparkmetal based off of the player's %Miner's Luck.

https://newworld.fandom.com/wiki/Gold_Vein

> Gold Veins produce Gold Ore and require level 45 in the Mining skill
> to gather. They have the potential to produce **Tier II & III Raw
> Gemstones** as well as Sparkmetal based off of the player's Miner's
> Luck.

https://newworld.fandom.com/wiki/Starmetal_Vein

> Starmetal Veins produce Starmetal Ore and require level 100 in the
> Mining skill to gather. They have the potential to produce **Tier II,
> III & IV Raw Gemstones** as well as Sparkmetal based off of the
> player's %Miner's Luck.

https://newworld.fandom.com/wiki/Orichalcum_Vein

> Orichalcum Veins produce Orichalcum Ore and require 175 Mining skill
> to gather, and 135 to track.  Drop rate of rare resources depend on
> one's Mining Luck.    **Brilliant (Tier IV) Raw Gemstones  Pristine
> (Tier V) Raw Gemstones**

Comment: I should have checked the game wiki out some first - but most times I've looked at it for other things it has been fairly incomplete due to the game's age I assume.

Comment: @TimmyJim As with any wiki, Fandom.com is only as good as the people maintaining it. Some games I play have wikis that are complete and fairly detailed, but others are skeletons with out of date information from alpha releases that haven't been relevant in years. I still find it valuable to have a current answer from someone that really knows what's going on.